# Should a `.barrier` on a concurrent queue become active immediately?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, swift3, xcode8

I'm not sure if this broke in xcode8 beta 5. Look at this code. Do you think it should print "A" first, or "B" first?

```
let q = DispatchQueue(label: "q", attributes: .concurrent)
q.async(flags: .barrier) {
  Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.25)
  print("A")
}
q.sync {
  print("B")
}
```

Because of the `.barrier`, I think it should block the concurrent queue and print "A", "B", but it does not in the latest xcode beta.

Bug? Misunderstanding of .barrier? What do you think?

please note: I know this would print in the expected order if I used a serial queue--this is a tiny part of a much larger system and I need to understand this behavior in isolation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a bug fixed in beta 6.

In beta 5, not only does it not behave the way you'd expect, but the `.onQueueAsBarrier` precondition fails, too. The problem would appear to be buried in `async` with the `.barrier` option, because if you perform it via equivalent Objective-C API, `dispatch_barrier_async`, it works fine, e.g.:

```
let q = DispatchQueue(label: "q", attributes: .concurrent)

BarrierExperiment.dispatchBarrierAsync(q) {
    dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueueAsBarrier(q))
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.25)
    print("A")
}

q.async() {
    print("B")
}
```

Where

```
@interface BarrierExperiment : NSObject

+ (void)dispatchBarrierAsync:(dispatch_queue_t)queue block:(void (^)())block;

@end

@implementation BarrierExperiment

+ (void)dispatchBarrierAsync:(dispatch_queue_t)queue block:(void (^)())block {
    dispatch_barrier_async(queue, block);
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the ObjC comparison! I filed it with the Swift team: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2335 I've been impressed with the transparency of that platform, rather than Apple's. Maybe this code is owned by Apple though? It's hard to tell for me.